# GETTING ERROR of MYSQL / CONNECTION at Delhi University Website

Tags: mysql, web, database-connection, server

I am getting this error

Database Connection Failed
Error: Connection refused (2002)
Function Performed: CONNECT

at Delhi University website. http://www.du.ac.in/du/ . Solve this issue.

Comment: _'Solve this issue.'_ - barking orders at us is unlikely to get you any help.

Answer (score -1):

Are you are Web Developer at **Delhi University**. You can report it back to DU support team. This is a MYSQL DATABSE ERROR.

Right now admission process of DU 2015/ with merit list & Admission List is available on HOME PAGE. If you want to know more about ADMISSION PROCESS/ IMP DATE CHECK http://goo.gl/1eFVAz

Comment: Okay Thanks. but what about the Main Website of Delhi University.